# Error "The play() request was interrupted by a call to pause()." in jPlayer

Tags: jquery, jplayer

I have got this error in my console in Chrome:

> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play() request was interrupted by a call to pause().

Next to the error there is a link describing the error, the cause of the error and how to solve it, but I don't get it to work.

There are similar/related questions here at Stackoverflow, but none provides a solution (for jplayer).

I am using an old javascript libary jPlayer (version 2.9.2). It has not been updated for many years and the project is completely dead. I still am using it though (not really having another choice).

I tried to fix it using a promise, but that doesn't work. Example:

```js
$jPlayer.jPlayer("setMedia", track);
    
var playPromise = $jPlayer.jPlayer("play");
    
if (playPromise !== undefined) {
  playPromise.then(_ => {
    // Automatic playback started!
    // Show playing UI.
  })
  .catch(error => {
    // Auto-play was prevented
    // Show paused UI.
  });
}
```

This results in "*Uncaught TypeError: playPromise.then is not a function*". `$jPlayer.jPlayer("play")` doesn't return a promise. So how to solve it?

When I look at one of the demo pages of jplayer "[demo-02-jPlayerPlaylist.html](https://jplayer.dubbel16.nl/examples/blue.monday/demo-02-jPlayerPlaylist.html)" and I switch play lists, something similar happens. When I try to 'auto play' the list with

```js
alert('play click');
$('.jp-play').click(); //auto play new list!
```

The first song should start playing, but it doesn't. If I turn these 2 lines around, the song starts to play and stops after 1 second. I am quite sure this is because of the "[Autoplay policy in Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/autoplay/)". No error here, but I think it is 100% related.

So do you know how to fix this?
Note: I am not limited to the code of the JPlayer library. I can modify it to my liking.

Comment: Please add a minimal, reproducible code example that shows how we can get the error message "Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play() request was interrupted by a call to pause()." with jplayer. Was this also because you tried to play a track without previous user interaction?

Comment: Isn't this example from the jplayer homepage exactly what you are looking for: https://www.jplayer.org/latest/quick-start-guide/example-audio-soundtrack/ ?

Comment: @Markus: I had a look at the example, but it doesn't make any difference. I provided an example which shows the same problem. It is not very easy to create a CodePen or Fiddle for this, but I will give it a try. There is user action (switching playlists) so that should give me enough to trigger the playing  of the 1st song in the second list.

Comment: Please share a reproducible example of your code that shows what you want to do and that produces the error message "Uncaught (in promise) DOMException".